# Encrypt strings with chars below ASCII 127 in Python

Tags: python, encryption, non-ascii-characters

I´m using this pair of functions to encrypt and desencrypt small strings. Always smaller than the key "s2".

The functions work great with any string where all chars are below ascii 127, but fail when I use them with strings such as "¡hola!" or "canción".

Encoding "¡hola!" gets b'\xc2\xa1hola!', and that format is crushing the results of desencrypt_str()

I´ve tried a few approaches but I cannot make them work.

Any ideas on how to improve the functions?

```
s2 = "A9BS03JJDJS9375MFJ498DJSWL59S"   # a string as "key", assume it´s longer than any s1

def encrypt_str(s1):
  try:
    j = "".join([chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(s1, s2)])    # XOR
    j = "".join(carac.encode('utf-8').hex() for carac in j)              # converts to hexa chars
    return j                                                         # a readable string
  except:
    return ""


def desencrypt_str(s1):
  try:
    s1 = bytes.fromhex(s1)                                         # encrypted string with hexa values
    j = "".join([chr(c1 ^ ord(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(s1, s2)])   # reverts XOR
    return j                               # the original string
  except:
    return ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Decryption must be done in inverse order to encryption.

First, in `encrypt_str` the line:

```
j = "".join(carac.encode('utf-8').hex() for carac in j)
```

is functionally identical to:

```
j = j.encode('utf-8').hex()
```

whose inverse is:

```
s1 = bytes.fromhex(s1).decode('utf-8')
```

whereas with respect to the labeling in `desencrypt_str` `s1` was used instead of `j`.

The inverse of the XOR-operation is the XOR-operation itself, i.e. the line

```
j = "".join([chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(s1, s2)])
```

is identical for encryption and decryption. For decryption `s1` denotes the ciphertext and `s2` the key.

This results in the following for decryption:

```
def desencrypt_str(s1):
    try:
        s1 = bytes.fromhex(s1).decode('utf-8')                         
        j = "".join([chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(s1, s2)])    
        return j                               
    except:
        return ""
```

Here plaintext and key may contain any Unicode character, e.g.

```
s2 = "€9ΩS0αJDJS9375MFJ498DJSWL59S"
ciphertext = encrypt_str("¡hola!canción€")
plaintext = desencrypt_str(ciphertext)
print(plaintext)
```

displays `¡hola!canción€`.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco. I´m getting this in Python3 interpreter:

>>> t1 = "English"

>>> t2 = "Español"

>>> bytes.fromhex(t1).decode('utf-8')


ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

>>> bytes.fromhex(t2).decode('utf-8')


ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 4

Comment: When do you get this error, when running the posted example? [Here](https://repl.it/repls/VisibleSelfishApplets) you can find a working (Python 3) implementation, please compare it with your code.

Comment: At the variable level, it works great. In my Python3 code, I am reading the plaint text from a file, encrypting it, and saving it as cipher text in another file. For what I´ve seen (I´m working in Windows), the strings are saved as "┬íhola!" and "canci├│n"  (I hope you can see the non-ASCII chars. Those special chars are causing the error.

Comment: Your current question / posted code does not deal with file I/O in any way. Please post a _complete, but minimal and executable_ code that allows to reproduce the problem _as a whole_. And where does the posted plaintext come from, is this the content of the plaintext file or the output of a hex editor? Is the plaintext file reliable, i.e. can corruption be excluded? Please do not answer this in a comment, but add the missing information to the question (i.e. either ask a new question or edit the current question by appending the information **at the end**). Thanks.

Comment: Solved by saving the source plain text file as ANSI in the text editor, and using .encode('ascii') when encrypting and .decode('ansi') when decrypting. Thanks a lot @Topaco for you help.